# Google tag manager get h2 innertext

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to set up a variable which gets the inner text of the second h2 within header tag, any help is appreciated. thank you.

```
    <header>
     <h2>I don't need this</h2> 
  </header>
     <header>
      <h2>This innertext I need</h2>
      </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return the `innerText` of the `h2` inside the second `header`:

```
  function() {
    var headerElement = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[1];
    var h2Element = headerElement.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
    var innerText = h2Element.innerText;
    console.log('The text you need is: ' + innerText);
    return innerText;
  }
```

In addition, assuming that your html code is NOT going to have any other `h2` element and you always want to retrieve the same `h2` element you can try:

```
 function() {
    var h2Element = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[1];
    var innerText = h2Element.innerText;
    console.log('The text you need is: ' + innerText);
    return innerText;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake... the first h2 is in a header tag too... :S